# Why do the hash values differ for NaN and Inf - Inf?

Tags: r, math, hash, digest

I use this hash function a lot, i.e. to record the value of a dataframe. Wanted to see if I could break it. Why aren't these hash values identical?

This requires the digest package.

Plain text output:

```
> digest(Inf-Inf)
[1] "0d59b2dae9351c1ce6c76133295322d7"
> digest(NaN)
[1] "4e9653ddf814f0d16b72624aeb85bc20"
> digest(1)
[1] "6717f2823d3202449301145073ab8719"
> digest(1 + 0)
[1] "6717f2823d3202449301145073ab8719"
> digest(5)
[1] "5e338704a8e069ebd8b38ca71991cf94"
> digest(sum(1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
[1] "5e338704a8e069ebd8b38ca71991cf94"
> digest(1^0)
[1] "6717f2823d3202449301145073ab8719"
> 1^0
[1] 1
> digest(1)
[1] "6717f2823d3202449301145073ab8719"
```

Additional weirdness. Calculations that equal NaN have identical hash values, but NaN's hash values are not equivalent:

```
> Inf - Inf
[1] NaN
> 0/0
[1] NaN
> digest(Inf - Inf)
[1] "0d59b2dae9351c1ce6c76133295322d7"
> digest(0/0)
[1] "0d59b2dae9351c1ce6c76133295322d7"
> digest(NaN)
[1] "4e9653ddf814f0d16b72624aeb85bc20"
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. You could ask Dirk directly to fix it and and add a unit test for this particular case.

Comment: What is the type of NaN if input directly? It is probably numeric/double when it results from a subtraction of a division operation.

Comment: yes, it's numeric; `str(Inf-Inf)` and `str(NaN)` are both "num NaN" (and `identical(Inf-Inf,NaN)` is TRUE ...

Comment: @OlegSklyar, class of NaN and class of operations that equal NaN (0/0, Inf - Inf) is "numeric".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**tl;dr** this has to do with very deep details of how `NaN`s are represented in binary.  You could work around it by using `digest(.,ascii=TRUE)` ...

Following up on @Jozef's answer: note boldfaced digits ...

```
> base::serialize(Inf-Inf,connection=NULL)
[1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 03 06 00 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00
[26] 00 0e 00 00 00 01 ff f8 00 00 00 00 00 00
> base::serialize(NaN,connection=NULL)
[1] 58 0a 00 00 00 03 00 03 06 00 00 03 05 00 00 00 00 05 55 54 46 2d 38 00 00
[26] 00 0e 00 00 00 01 7f f8 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Alternatively, using `pryr::bytes()` ...

```
> bytes(NaN)
[1] "7F F8 00 00 00 00 00 00"
> bytes(Inf-Inf)
[1] "FF F8 00 00 00 00 00 00"
```

The [Wikipedia article on floating point format/NaNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#NaN) says:

> Some operations of floating-point arithmetic are invalid, such as taking the square root of a negative number. The act of reaching an invalid result is called a floating-point exception. An exceptional result is represented by a special code called a NaN, for "Not a Number". All NaNs in IEEE 754-1985 have this format:
>
> - sign = either 0 or 1.
> - biased exponent = all 1 bits.
> - fraction = anything except all 0 bits (since all 0 bits represents infinity).

The sign is the first bit; the exponent is the next 11 bits; the fraction is the last 52 bits. Translating the first four hex digits given above to binary, `Inf-Inf` is `1111 1111 1111 0100` (sign=1; exponent is all ones, as required; fraction starts with `0100`) whereas `NaN` is `0111 1111 1111 0100` (the same, but with sign=0).

To understand *why* `Inf-Inf` ends up with sign bit 1 and `NaN` has sign bit 0 you'd probably have to dig more deeply into the way floating point arithmetic is implemented on this platform ...

It might be worth raising an [issue on the digest GitHub repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/digest/issues) about this; I can't think of an *elegant* way to do it, but it seems reasonable that objects where `identical(x,y)` is `TRUE` in R should have identical hashes ...  Note that `identical()` specifically ignores these differences in bit patterns via the `single.NA` (default `TRUE`) argument:

> single.NA: logical indicating if there is conceptually just one numeric
>             ‘NA’ and one ‘NaN’; ‘single.NA = FALSE’ differentiates bit
>             patterns.

Within the C code, it looks like R simply uses C's `!=` operator to compare `NaN` values *unless* bitwise comparison is enabled, in which case it does an explicit check of equality of the memory locations: see [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/main/identical.c#L351-L366).  That is, C's comparison operator appears to treat different kinds of `NaN` values as equivalent ...

Comment: Awesome, thanks.The point about some operations of floating-point arithmetic being invalid is a great one.

Comment: Negative infinity is obviously bigger than positive infinity making the result negative. After all, any 2's compliment stored number has one more negative value than positive value. It's science.

Comment: There's a good story floating around of a programmer who changed some C code that compared two arrays of floats element-by-element with a simple `memcmp` of the two arrays. It passed all unit tests but failed horribly for a key customer. There's the +0/-0 thing, the NaN!=NaN thing, and so on.

Comment: @corsiKa [IEEE 754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats) numbers are not 2's complement! They're more like sign-magnitude, which has equal ranges in the negative and the positive. You can easily see this, because floats know both +0 and -0.

Comment: @marcelm I guess you didn't umm.. get the joke. Obviously, mathematically positive nor negative infinity's size can be measured, making the first statement non-sensical... it follows the the rest of the statement is also non-sensical... so yeah... <3

Comment: @corsiKa Fair enough! You never know :P

Answer (score 8):

This has to do with `digest::digest` using `base::serialize`, which gives non-identical results for the 2 mentioned objects with `ascii = FALSE`, which is the default passed to it by `digest`:

```
identical(
  base::serialize(Inf-Inf, connection = NULL, ascii = FALSE),
  base::serialize(NaN, connection = NULL, ascii = FALSE)
)
# [1] FALSE
```

Even though

```
identical(Inf-Inf, NaN)
# [1] TRUE
```